# How to get count of elements in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I created an array and put the value into array as follow

```
int *ptr_int;
int list_int[10];
int i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    list_int[i] = i + 1;
```

and I assign a value into `list_int` array like this

```
list_int[17] = 18;
```

When I tried to get the count of array as follow

```
int size = sizeof(list_int ) / sizeof( int );
printf( "The size of int is %d.\n", size);
```

the result is only `10`.

How could I get the array room count?

Comment: C arrays don't automagically resize.

Comment: If I want to add/extend the array, how can I do?

Comment: @ThuRa: Switch from automatic allocation/freeing to to dynamic allocation/reallocation/freeing.

Comment: @alk, I'm coming from web. I've a little experience at C. So I'm not clear understand how to do it. Do you have any recommend site to do this? I'm very appreciate to you.

Comment: @ThuRa: Read about dynamic memory allocation in general and the system calls `malloc()`/`calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` in particular. Do some tests leaning how to use them and if getting stuck using them come back here to Stackoverflow presenting your findings and issues posing another question and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 6):

> the result is only 10.

That's the real size. Assigning to `list_int[17]` is undefined behavior, and it does not magically extend the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_int[17] = 18;
```

This is undefined behavior because the array size is only 10.

Note that with the exception of variable length arrays, `sizeof` operator is a compile time operator. The result of `sizeof(list_int )` and `sizeof(int)` are determined in compile time.

---

To implement an array with dynamic size, you need to allocate the array dynamically, you may find `realloc` pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have already defined the max size of your array as 10 with the following definition

```
int list_int[10];
```

You can not assign value to `list_int[17]`. Becacuse `list_int[17]` is out of the memory of the array `list_int[10]` that you have defined.

You can only assign value to the element from 0 .. 9

Comment: We can assign but **we should not** because it is Undefined behaviour :).

Answer (score 1):

To Create Dynamic arrays ( allocated at run time )

```
int n; 

scanf("%d",&n); // read n from the user at run time 

int* x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);  // where n is the number of elements you need to allocate

////// after that you can access the array (x) using indexer 

///// reading loop 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%d",&x[i]);
```

===============================================================================

Note: if you need more dynamic data structure which can allocate memory for each entry 
you can use linked lists